# Change The Size of the SubWindow and the Area It Covers In Unity

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, rendering, unityscript

I'm creating a simple 2D racing game in Unity. The game has another subwindow that displays the enemy's view. Kinda like a small screen on top; that lets you know where your enemy is or what he's doing.

Currently, I'm using a secondary camera to follow the enemy and a render texture to limit the display of the subwindow as well as its size.

However, I want the size of the window to be flexible like if i want the ratio of the window to be 4:3 instead of a perfect square. With my current implementation, whenever I rescale the subwindow, it just rescales everything up including the view being displayed. What I want to happen is, when I rescale the subwindow, the area being displayed should just be wider. It should just cover more area because I made the window wider. I want the view to be independent.

Is there a way to do this with my current implementation? If not, how can I achieve what I want?

I'm new to Unity so I really hope someone could teach me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The are viewed is independant of the size of your window, if you want to change how much is displayed instead of just re fitting the same content in another size you'll have to work with the field of view http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-fieldOfView.html